# How can I reduce "palm touch sensitivity" on my Thinkpad?

Tags: touchpad, thinkpad

Am running 14.04.4 on my Thinkpad L450 - however I have noted the touchpad is very sensitive to my palm rubbing against the touchpad when I use the TrackPoint nub.

How can I reduce the sensitivity of the touchpad to accidental palm touches.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably Synaptics touchpad, you can change your preferences in `Mouse & Touchpad` settings. If this doesn't help you can play with specific Synaptic settings by `synclient` command. Type `synclien -l` to list all possible settings

You can also check this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad#Control_touchpad_features_using_synclient